# Jetpack compose memory leak in clickable?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Can anyone explain how the following ways may have memory leak?  LeakyCanary is complaining about these.

*Note memory leaks were complained when these texts have not been clicked on.

One way is:

```
Text(text = stringResource(string.save),
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable {
            WeakReference(this@MyActivity).get()?.save()
         }
)
```

The second is:

```
val activity = activity_ as? MyActivity
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
Text(text = stringResource(string.save),
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable {
            coroutineScope.launch { activity?.save() }
        }
)
```

Comment: This is useless. You're creating a weak reference on the spot, use it, then it gets discarded. Move your logic to a viewmodel instead of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

To answer it myself.  Through consulting chatGPT and Bard and experimenting, my understanding now is this.

As `save()` is a member function of the activity, the closure after clickable captures and holds a reference to the activity during composition. This reference, if not explicitly cleared when the activity is destroyed, causes the memory leak.

While I don't understand why the use of WeakReference didn't help, the right way of doing it seems the following:

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
DisposableEffect(coroutineScope) {
    onDispose {
        coroutineScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

..........

```
Text(text = stringResource(string.save),
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable {
            coroutineScope.launch { save() }
        }
)
```

The first part with the DisposableEffect is in the same composable function as the Text.  When the activity is destroyed, onDispose will be called which cancels the coroutine scope and clears any references in the scope.

Anyone has other thoughts?

Another artifact I discovered with this is that `stringResource(string.save)` causes the composition to happen twice (on which Google stated as an intended behavior). Though the double composition is annoying, it doesn't seem to cause further complications with memory leaks.